# Cant show the list of images in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Upload, Button, Form } from "antd";
import { UploadOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const fileList = [
  {
    uid: "-1",
    name: "xxx.png",
    status: "done",
    url:
      "https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/jkjgkEfvpUPVyRjUImniVslZfWPnJuuZ.png",
    thumbUrl:
      "https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/jkjgkEfvpUPVyRjUImniVslZfWPnJuuZ.png"
  },
  {
    uid: "-2",
    name: "yyy.png",
    status: "error"
  }
];

console.log(fileList);
const Demo = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([...fileList]);
  const add = () => {
    setState([
      ...state,
      {
        uid: "-3",
        name: "xxdx.png",
        status: "done",
        url:
          "https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/jkjgkEfvpUPVyRjUImniVslZfWPnJuuZ.png",
        thumbUrl:
          "https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/jkjgkEfvpUPVyRjUImniVslZfWPnJuuZ.png"
      }
    ]);
  };

  const onRemove = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    setState(state.filter((i) => i.uid !== e.uid));
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Form
        name="validate_other"
        initialValues={{
          "input-number": 3,
          "checkbox-group": ["A", "B"],
          rate: 3.5
        }}
      >
        <button onClick={add}>add</button>
        <Form.Item name="upload" label="Upload" valuePropName="fileList">
          <Upload
            action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76"
            listType="picture"
            fileList={[...state]}
            onRemove={onRemove}
          >
            <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Upload</Button>
          </Upload>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Above should appear a form with the upload component inside that has a list of images by default. To show these images i added: `fileList={[...state]}`, but it does not work, but if remove the form  and the form input outside the uploader, the images appear bellow the uploader. I know that antd Form has `initialValues`, but in my situation i can't use this, so i have to use `fileList`. Why the images don't appear and how to solve this?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/pictures-with-list-style-antd4130-forked-umels?file=/index.js:0-1840

Comment: You cannot pre-populate value of a file picker from a script

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova , do you mean that it is impossible to do what I want?

Comment: No, at least not the way you're attempting to. What are you trying to do btw? What is the aim of adding these files to upload?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova, i need `fileList` because in this way i will have inside my upload all images  thatt will come from backend.

Comment: File picker is normally used for uploading files from the user's machine. Imagine I created a form with an invisible file picker and added half of your hard-drive to it, that would be unfortunate, wouldn't it? So the browsers don't allow this to happen. Your files, however, look more like web links, why do you even want them in the form?